# How to execute a JS function which is inside PHP tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, react-native

I have this below code in a file named `test.php`, whose task is to create a JSON object and transfer it to a function in JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Payment Receipt</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if($row) {
    $obj->txndate = $row['date'];
    $obj->txnid = $row['txnid'];
    $obj->atomid = $row['atomid'];
    $obj->amount = $row['amount'];
    
    $myJSON = json_encode($obj);
    $encodedJSON = json_encode($myJSON); //final variable in PHP to pass to below function.
    
    //JS begins here

    echo <<<JS001
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var msg = {$encodedJSON};
    var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = {
        postMessage: function (message) {
            if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
                window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(message);
            } else {
                window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');'
            }
        }
    };
    ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage(msg);
    alert(msg);
    </script>
JS001;
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect ID';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have this piece of script, but I can only write it inside PHP - because the value the function requires, is stored in a PHP variable. All it should do is fetch the PHP's `encodedJSON` variable's value and store it in a local JS variable `msg`. Then, I created a function whose task is to POST a message, and called it next. All this worked perfectly when run in a separate HTML file, in which JS was written individually.

What should I do, to make the JS piece of code run inside PHP code? Thanks!

Comment: I usually do either: 1. Similar to what you have done except in a variable (e.g. $jsString = ""; then echo the string inside <script> tags. OR 2. Write JS code normally (either externally in another JS file or in the HTML) and set a global style variable in the PHP. So the idea is the JS code (written anywhere) uses a variable defined in the PHP view/file... whatever (e.g. var jsCode = '<?= $phpCode; ?''; ) that is all. then in your JS script use jsCode to do what you want. NOTE: usually I do this with jquery and $(document).ready() to make sure all variables are ready to use. Hope that helps

Comment: NOTE: PHP is executed prior to JS so JS will not run inside PHP code.

Comment: PHP executes on the server. You cannot call browser APIs such as postMessage on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `$myjson` contains the `json` string in `php`, then

```
var msg = {$myJSON};
```

to understand better above code is equivalent to:

```
var msg = JSON.parse('{$myJSON}')
```

is the way to convert it to js object from php variable.

Please see comments in the code for further help.

Please run below code and see how `console.log` is printing the `json` object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Payment Receipt</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
//started with hard coded data to show a working copy paste example
$row = array('date'=>'09-Oct-2020','txnid'=>1234,'atomid'=>456,'amount'=>21345);

if($row) {
    $obj = new stdclass(); //op should add this to avoid warning
    $obj->txndate = $row['date'];
    $obj->txnid = $row['txnid'];
    $obj->atomid = $row['atomid'];
    $obj->amount = $row['amount'];
    
    $myJSON = json_encode($obj);
    //to see the json encode value in php
    //var_dump($myJSON); 
    //this is not needed in op code
    //$encodedJSON = json_encode($myJSON); //final variable in PHP to pass to below function.
    
    //JS begins here

    echo <<<JS001
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //php json string is converted to js object here
    var msg = {$myJSON};
    //see msg object printed in console
    console.log(msg);
    </script>
JS001;
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect ID';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSON is already valid JavaScript (hence the name), do there is no need to decode anything: `var msg = $myJSON;`.